# Link Error: Duplicate Symbol

Tags: c++, linker, header-files, c++17, duplicate-symbol

I have 4 source files listed below:

```
//a.h

#pragma once

namespace proj {
class A {} a;
} // namespace proj
```

---

```
//b.h

#pragma once

namespace proj {
int foo();
} // namespace proj
```

---

```
// b.cpp

#include "proj/a.h"

namespace proj {
int foo() {
  A b = a;
  return 0;
}
} // namespace proj
```

---

```
// c.cpp

#include "proj/a.h"
#include "proj/b.h"

using namespace proj;

int main() {
  A b = a;
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile `c.cpp` I get the following link error:

```
duplicate symbol proj::a      in:
    buck-out/gen/proj/c#compile-c.cpp.ob5f76e97,default/c.cpp.o
    buck-out/gen/proj/b#default,static/libb.a(b.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol ___odr_asan._ZN4proj1aE in:
    buck-out/gen/proj/c#compile-c.cpp.ob5f76e97,default/c.cpp.o
    buck-out/gen/proj/b#default,static/libb.a(b.cpp.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build failed: Command failed with exit code 1.
stderr: duplicate symbol proj::a      in:
    buck-out/gen/proj/c#compile-c.cpp.ob5f76e97,default/c.cpp.o
    buck-out/gen/proj/b#default,static/libb.a(b.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol ___odr_asan._ZN4proj1aE in:
    buck-out/gen/proj/c#compile-c.cpp.ob5f76e97,default/c.cpp.o
    buck-out/gen/proj/b#default,static/libb.a(b.cpp.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I assume this is happening because b.cpp is compiled independently from c.cpp and so the pre-processor includes the header a.h in each file individually and when it comes time to link, the linker finds two versions of the symbol a.

How do I declare one instance of a class (in this case `a`) that is usable across my entire program and avoid the above link error?

## Reference

I am using gcc-7 (`gcc-7 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0_1) 7.2.0`) on Mac OS X 10.13.3 with `-std=c++17`.

### Build system

This should be irrelevant to the question, but including anyways in case someone finds it helpful.

I am using [buck](https://buckbuild.com/) to compile the code (although this should be irrelevant) with the following BUCK file:

```
cxx_library(
    name='a',
    exported_headers=['a.h'],
    visibility=['PUBLIC'],
)

cxx_library(
    name='b',
    exported_headers=['b.h'],
    srcs = ['b.cpp'],
    deps = [':a'],
    visibility=['PUBLIC'],
)

cxx_binary(
    name='c',
    srcs = ['c.cpp'],
    deps = [':a', ':b'],
)
```

Comment: Your `a.h` declares a variable `class A {} a;` so every cpp file that includes `a.h` redeclares `proj::a`. You need to declare it in only 1 cpp file and as extern in `a.h`

Comment: Let's take a step back. You seem to be using `a` as a "default value". Why?

Comment: So for my "actual" use case, my class does some expensive set up work and for most cases I just need a default instantiation of the class. So, rather than re-instantiating every time, I just want one instance accessible across the whole program.

Comment: But you are copying it all over the place. If the default construction is so expansive, is copying really so cheap?

Comment: As far as I can tell (from this simple example: https://godbolt.org/g/RQWwi5), it should not be copying the object all over the place. In the code example I gave, yes I am copying it, but that's just to show usage. In my actual code, I just reference the declared object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is tagged C++17, you can take advantage of the new [inline variables](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf) language feature:

```
namespace proj {
    class A {};
    inline A a;
} // namespace proj
```

`inline` variables now behave the same way as `inline` functions: your multiple definitions of `a` get collapsed into one.

Comment: Do they get collapsed into one, or are they instantiated multiple times (once per compilation unit)?

Answer (score 1):

### For pre *c++17* standard release solutions:<sup>1</sup>

The reason for the linker error is quite obvious

```
//a.h

#pragma once

namespace proj {
    class A {} a; // Declares proj::A proj::a implicitly as an instance
                  // everywhere a.h is included.
                  // Thus the linker gets confused which one to use primarly.
}
```

#### Alternative 1 (one single instance):

> How do I declare one instance of a class (in this case a) that is usable across my entire program and avoid the above link error?

```
// a.h
#pragma once

namespace proj {
    class A {};
    extern A a;
}
```

---

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.h"

namespace proj {
    proj:A a;
}
```

#### Alternative 2 (an instance per translation unit):

```
// a.h
#pragma once

namespace proj {
    class A {};
}
```

---

```
// b.cpp   
#include "a.h"

namespace { // <<< unnamed (aka anonymous) namespace
            //     privately visible for translation unit
    proj:A a;
}
```

---

```
// c.cpp   
#include "a.h"

namespace {
    proj:A a;
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Otherwise probably [@Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48693849/9212993) applies best.</sub>